# Ubuntu | Apache - No permission to request ressource after changing DocumentRoot

Tags: apache, ubuntu, web

I am currently setting up a development environment with Apache and Ubuntu for a Git project.

However, when I adjust the documentRoot under `sites-availabe`, I get the message "403 Forbidden" by calling the site in the browser.

The default directory under */var/www/html* can be displayed without any problems.
However, if I change the path to */var/www/my-project.com*, I get the 403 message.

I also copied the permissions from the folder "html", so there shouldn't be any problems here.

**000-default.conf**

```
ServerAdmin xxx@xxx.xx
DocumentRoot /var/www/xxxxx.com
ServerName xxxxx.com
ServerAlias www.xxxxx.com
```

**apache2.conf**

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 hostname
127.0.0.1 xxxxx.com
```

Permissions of /var/www/xxxxx.com

```
drwxrwxr-x 7 user:www-data
```

I have also completely reinstalled Apache, but that didn't help either.
(Im using Ubuntu 20.04 with Apache 2.4)

I would be very grateful for any help.

Edit: Also after copying the files to the html directory ends up in 403 when calling specific files. But i still can call the standard index.html from apache.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. Because im really new to Ubuntu i didn't recognized the broken Symlink. After recreating it with

```
ln -s sourceDirectory newLinkDirectory
```

all works just fine